# new row violates row-level security policy for table "stories"

Tags: supabase, supabase-js

I am writing a script to scrap data from web and insert data into DB as an Admin. I want a user with specific email only should be able to insert any new record in the table.

```
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({ // Sign in as admin user
    email: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    password: '*********',
  })
  console.log('login data', data) // prints all the session and user object
  console.log('login error', error) // prints null

  if (!error && data.session?.access_token && data.session?.refresh_token) {
    const { data: setSessionData, error: setSessionError } = await supabase.auth.setSession({
      access_token: data.session?.access_token,
      refresh_token: data.session?.refresh_token,
    })
    console.log('last session', await supabase.auth.getSession())
    // prints 'last session { data: { session: null }, error: null }'
  }

  const { error: insertError } = await supabase.from('stories').insert([record]) // record is the object that is already created above this code.
  console.log('error', insertError) 
  /* prints 'error {
  code: '42501',
  details: null,
  hint: null,
  message: 'new row violates row-level security policy for table "stories"'
  }' 
  */
  const { error: logutError } = await supabase.auth.signOut()
  console.log('logutError', logutError) // prints 'logutError null' means working
```

Login and Logout is working. I don't know why getSession is not working after successful login.

Below is the admin insert policy that is not allowing insert.
[image: See insert RLS policy]

I tried allowing the RLS policy for all anon users it is working. But not working when I apply the admin insert only policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [Service Roke Key](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/api-keys#the-servicerole-key) to initialize your Supabase instance in order to bypass RLS.

`getSession` is not working, because you are calling it from a node environment and not on the web. If you want to insert data from a server, enable RLS and do not set any policies. This way, the data is protected from the public, but you can still insert data using the service role key.